# C++: Boost::mutex individually locking multiple variables in same scope

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I'm new to multi-threading and am trying to use mutexes.  I'm pretty sure that I understand what the CONCEPT of what mutexes are, however I'm finding the documentation on actually using them to be quite lacking.  One of the main issues that I'm having is trying to control access to specific variables.

What exactly happens when I lock a mutex (regardless of which kind of lock I use)?  There doesn't seem to be any way of assigning specific variables/resources to mutexes, so does it just lock all variables in scope?  What if I have variable `A` and variable `B` both declared in the same scope which I want to be mutexed individually (i.e. thread 1 can access variable `A` WHILE thread 2 accesses variable `B`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Mutex* locks access to every *scope* it protects, it does not lock variables themselves.

If you want to protect single *variable*, wrap it with [`std::atomic<T>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/) or [`boost::atomic<T>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/atomic.html) respectively, or dedicate separate mutex for each.

Answer (score 1):

Mutexes don't get assigned explicitly to variables.  It is more of an association that you are making as a developer that when the mutex is locked, the thread that got the lock gets to mess around with whatever variables you want protected.

One way to associate mutexes with variables is to have the variables being protected held in a structure together with the mutex.  So for example, if I had a vector of integers that I wanted to make sure was only accessed by one thread at a time, I could create a structure like:

```
struct VectorDataType {
   boost::mutex theLock;
   std::vector<int> theData;
};

VectorDataType myVector;
```

Then anytime I wanted to modify the integer vector, I would make sure to first get the lock, and likewise remember to unlock it after I'm done:

```
myVector.theLock.lock();
myVector.theData.push_back(1234);
myVector.theLock.unlock();
```

It may already be obvious, but keep in mind if you want to keep a mutex in a structure with the data it protects, you can't make copies of instances of that structure, since a mutex is not copyable.